# I can't put my java jdk7 file into my usr/lib because it says Permission denied when I click show more

Tags: installation, java, minecraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)

It gives me a error message saying that I need to have permission. My account is unlocked so I assumed that would fix it but that did nothing. Perhaps there is a way to do this via the terminal where I could enter my password for things like this. I need the JDK to run minecraft so, yah, for someone like me this is pretty important.

Comment: You need to use ROOT permissions to modify usr/lib. If you gave some more information as to what you are doing exactly we might be able to help. Are you getting jdk7 from a PPA or what not.

Comment: How do i get root permissions. As previously stated I am downloading jdk7. I got the download from the oracle page.

Answer (score 1):

Use repositories to install jdk7 - `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

Answer (score -1):

You have to use root, either sudo or gksu

```
gksu nautilus
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

So download the files, then transfer them

Comment: Thanks a lot man I'm new to linux so having you help me out was really helpful

Comment: A bad idea - don't install software manually, especially in /usr/lib, as t may break other packages. Use repositories or `/usr/local` for experiments