# What do I install to get Java to work on Ubuntu 11.10 running on Virtualbox?

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)

I have tried many things and nothing works.  What files do i need to download for this to work?  there is no internet connection in ubuntu, so I want to download 1 or 2 files and install from desktop.

I had a few different Java files that I tried, and Terminal says that it needs java-common and some other things.  WHY CAN"T IT JUST BE EASY???????????????

simple instructions for a simple man please!  Thank you for your help!!

Comment: If you have no internet connection - please follow the links in the bountied answer to install java from a tarball (JRE/JDK 6 or 7)

Comment: If the host is connected to the internet choose 'bridged' in network settings from the virtualbox manager to access internet via the host in your virtualized Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy because you work against the package management. In Linux, most things are split up in lots of packages, making it easy to install with tools like `apt-get`, but a pain to install manually.

I would recommend getting the internet connection to work in your guest and use the package manager there.

You might have luck with Oracle's Java that hopefully comes in one big file, but I have never used that.