# sun-java6-plugin has no installation candidate?

Tags: apt, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

I'm trying to install `sun-java6-plugin`. It supposedly in the "partner" repo.

I have:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner
```

in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and ran `apt-get update`.

I get:

```
apt-get install sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done    
Package sun-java6-plugin is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package sun-java6-plugin has no installation candidate
```

Does the package no longer exist, or do I need a different repo?

Comment: Sun Java can no longer be distributed through partner, the link I posted has options if you want to use openjdk or oracle java though.

Comment: @JorgeCastro: similar, but I wouldn't call it a dup since its a different version. There's enough differences between Ubuntu versions to make some instructions/solutions incompatible with others.

Comment: Can you point out which part isn't working for you? We like to put all version specific things in one question instead of all over the site.

Comment: after installing the icedtea6-plugin, it no longer complains about not having java, but the page does not load correctly.

Comment: ok, can you edit your question to be about that then? Make sure you mention which site you're trying to get it working on so people can test, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why:

"Oracle (Sun) Java 6 is no longer available to be distributed by Ubuntu, because of license issues.

It is recommended that users either migrate to OpenJDK, or download and install the newest version of Oracle (Sun) Java 6 manually, or switch to Oracle Java 7. Older versions of Oracle (Sun) Java 6 that have been distributed in the past are vulnerable to security exploits, see this announcement for more information.

If you wish, you can still install the newest and secure Oracle (Sun) Java 6 by a script (JRE only) or by a manual method. Both are easy to apply."

See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) for more info and a work-around.

Comment: I was able to install the jre successfully, so its still in the repos. It's just the browser plug-in that's been removed? I installed icedtea6-plugin but its not rendering the java-based page correctly. All the menus are missing.

Comment: For people who need "real" Java, here's how to do it easily: http://www.duinsoft.nl/packages.php?t=en