# Not a valid JAR when running HADOOP example

Tags: 14.04, hadoop, jar

I have installed hadoop-2.4.0 in my 14.04 LTS,

I have followed [this link](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/), I have done upto start and stop services successfully,

but when I tried to execute example,

```
$ /bin/hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output
```

and I am getting response as,

```
Not a valid JAR: /hadoop*examples*.jar
```

---

**EDIT 1**

I have installed JAVA 7(i.e JDK 1.7) and when I used Hadoop-1.0.3 it works fine.

Problem cause when I try to execute with Hadoop-2.4.0.

---

**NOTE**

From [this tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) my system differ the following,

> 1. I am using JAVA 7 instead of JAVA 6.
> 2. I am using Hadoop 2.4.0 instead of Hadoop-1.0.3
> 3. I am usinh Ubuntu 14.04 instead of Ubuntu 10.04.

And I can successfully execute HAdoop-1.0.3 with JAVA 7 on 14.04.

My question why can't I run the same for Hadoop-2.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is the solution.

OS - Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
Java - OpenJDK 7 
Hadoop - Hadoop 2.4.1

Step 1: create a hdfs directory for input: `hadoop dfs -mkdir -p /usr/local/hadoop/input`
Step 2: now paste the jar file into this folder using hadoop command.
`hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hduser/Desktop/sample.txt /usr/local/hadoop/input`
Step 3: Go to $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce folder in terminal.
`cd $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce`
`hadoop jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.1.jar wordcount /usr/local/hadoop/input/sample.txt /usr/local/hadoop/output`

Here /usr/local/hadoop/output folder will be created. Each time you have to give a new name. 
**NOTE:** you cannot simply list the folders input and output using `ls` in terminal.

Step 4: To view the output, use this:
`hadoop dfs -cat /usr/local/hadoop/output/part-r-00000`

Comment: I followed this only, I got error when i run example...

Comment: @ARUL, instead of using `hadoop*examples*.jar` , you need to use this jar `hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.4.1.jar` in the folder $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce. You are getting the error because you are not specifying the path for jar. So navigate to the folder using `cd $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce` and then run the jar. It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was also following the same tutorial and faced same issue with my latest install (hadoop 2.7.1). I had to change it from

```
$ /bin/hadoop jar hadoop*examples*.jar wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output
```

to

```
$ /bin/hadoop jar ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-*-examples*.jar  wordcount /user/hduser/gutenberg /user/hduser/gutenberg-output
```

Answer (score 0):

> This tutorial has been tested with the following software versions:
>
> Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTS (deprecated: 8.10 LTS, 8.04, 7.10, 7.04)

It hasn't been updated since 10.04 ~ 2012. That is (I would guess your problem).

14.04 and 10.04 work quite differently...

> Sun Java 6

[Sun Java is no longer avaliable in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/109212/186134) so that is also probably why it isn't working.

Comment: I didn't followed exactly the same as tutorial said, I am using Oracle Java(JDK 1.7) and I am using Hadoop 2.4.0, actually my problem isn't that.. I can do with Hadoop 1.0.3 sucessfully.. When I do with Hadoop 2.4.0 am getting this problem...

Comment: I have update my question, please take a look @Tim

Comment: Does this work? http://codesfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score -1):

I am using the hadoop-2.7.2 and to handle this problem, simply go to the directory hadoop-2.7.2 and instead of writing directly `hadop*exaples*jar` write the following:

```
share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about what to edit and how. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)