# Java command not found even after "sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk"

Tags: software-installation, java

I followed the instruction to set up Java on Ubuntu 11.10 from [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java).

I ran this command to install:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

After it succeeded and I typed `java`, I got this error:

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * gcj-4.4-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.5-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by manually setting java path with `/etc/profile`.

Add following lines to there.

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

Comment: You did not fix the broken package installation, you digged in and found the bin folder and put it first in your path.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Which broken package installation?

Comment: @userunknown If the `sudo ...`command did not result in a `java`command being present in $PATH, the package installation did not complete correctly and hence is broken!

Answer (score 11):

Did you try this command?

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This will list all the Java versions installed and configured.

If you see one or more installs, it will give you a list each element starting with a number. Just choose the number that corresponds to the version you want to use by default.

If you don't see any installed then something is not right. In that case take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-oracle-java-jre-7).

While that question is for Oracle Java 7, it lists methods common to both Java 6 and Java 7, for installing Java and getting Ubuntu to see and link to the new Java installation. If you want version 6, just download the version 6 JDK and follow the instructions provided in that question, changing the filename accordingly.

Comment: If when running update-alternatives, you get a message like `update-alternatives: warning: /etc/alternatives/java is dangling`, delete the dangling link (i.e. `sudo rm /etc/alternatives/java`) and run update-alternatives again.

Answer (score 3):

> **Note:** WebUpd8 team's PPA has been discontinued with effective from April 16, 2019. Thus this PPA doesn't have any Java files. More information can be found on [PPA's page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Ewebupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). Hence this method no longer works and exists because of historical reasons.

#### Install Oracle Java using the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a default java that you can set up by running *one* of the following commands, depending on your needs:

```
sudo apt install default-jre            
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: It's a bit strange to run *all* of these commands, since each one is by itself sufficient to install a JRE, and most of the time people just want one JRE. (Also, the JRE that the first one installs *may* be the same as one of the others.)

Comment: this answer isn't valid as it just suggests things to do instead of giving a clear and definite answer. Also the person wants the JDK and not the JRE.