# How to uninstall softwares installed with `apt-get`

Tags: apt, uninstall

I am a newbie and followed the instructions of the site:
http://sejalivre.org/instalando-o-java-6-update-30-no-ubuntu/
in order to install Java and some proprietary software based on Java on my Ubuntu 11.10 box.

According to that site, I should use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre icedtea-plugin
```

to install Java and the proprietary software.

I did that, but started to wonder if that script is clean and not some malware...
For my peace of mind I want to remove everything that was installed with that command.

Answer (score 6):

If you did not follow the second step *If your application does not work with **openjdk*** and added the PPA to your system then everything should be ok since you are using the package versions supplied by Ubuntu.

To remove the packages you have just installed do the opposite of what you just did to install them

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-6-jre icedtea-plugin
```

If you added the PPA to install Oracle's version of java there is no warranty of the quality of those packages. If you want more information on PPAs have a look at

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

For dangers related to adding PPAs to your system you should read also

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

There are good news tough. You can remove a PPA from your system and purge any packages that you have installed in your system with a small tool called `ppa-purge`. Learn how to install and use it by looking in to

- [Removing a PPA with ppa-purge](https://askubuntu.com/a/91660/25863)

If you need a proper way of installing Java in your system without using PPAs and packages created by other people you can choose and follow the instructions of doing so here

- [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)

Comment: Hi Bruno!That script installed receitanet as well. That's why I am worried about the safety of using the application...

Comment: Remove it if you are not sure with `ppa-purge`. If your not happy with it, your not happy with it. Don't install it. I have added instructions to a proper way of installing Oracle's Java implementation.