# How do I install Java?

Tags: installation, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-to-install-java)

First time ever using Ubuntu and I'm trying to learn it. I was wondering how do I install Java.

I downloaded "jre-6u31-linux-i586-rpm.bin" from the official Java website.

How do I install it? I know it's something too do with the Terminal?

Thanks guys. Really appreciate it. I'm a noob at this, but we all start somewhere.