# How to install java and enable java plug in for firefox in Ubuntu 12.04LTS?

Tags: 12.04, java, plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Please help me to install java and enable Java plug in for firefox. I tried Tools-add-ons-plugins. But I don't know how to do?