# I want to compile my java program but the terminal is showing this

Tags: java

```
zeeshan@zeeshan-desktop:~$ cd Desktop
zeeshan@zeeshan-desktop:~/Desktop$ ls
0x0409.ini  helloworld.c   setup.exe          why.java   WinRoot
hello       helloworld.c~  Turbo C++ 3.2.msi  why.java~
zeeshan@zeeshan-desktop:~/Desktop$ javac why
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
error: Class names, 'why', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested
1 error
zeeshan@zeeshan-desktop:~/Desktop$
```

what should i do??

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in your command

`javac why`

instead use

`javac why.java`

You can also see this problem is already solved in this community
**For more details visit this link**:
 - [How to compile a .java file on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145748/how-to-compile-a-java-file)

Comment: Welcome! then please check the green for vote :)