# Netbeans 8.1 on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, netbeans

I tried installing Netbeans by clicking on the apt link here : https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/netbeans

the installed package is "netbeans"

ergo : `sudo apt install netbeans`

the program runs the splash screen for a couple of seconds then crashes.

Any tips?

```
t@tsu:~/src/edk2$ netbeans 
Jun 08, 2017 8:57:06 PM org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory register
SEVERE: No way to find original stream handler for jar protocol
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field transient java.net.URLStreamHandler java.net.URL.handler accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.net" to unnamed module @6d8a00e3
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:337)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:281)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:169)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory.register(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.main(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.Main.main(Unknown Source)

Jun 08, 2017 8:57:06 PM org.openide.util.lookup.implspi.ActiveQueue reportError
WARNING: Cannot hack ReferenceQueue to fix bug #206621!
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.lock accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang.ref" to unnamed module @6d8a00e3
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:337)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:281)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:169)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.implspi.ActiveQueue$Impl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.implspi.ActiveQueue.queue(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup.activeQueue(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup$ReferenceToResult.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup$ReferenceToResult.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.Lookup.lookupResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.Lookup.lookupAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader.allCLIs(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.main(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.Main.main(Unknown Source)

Jun 08, 2017 8:57:06 PM org.openide.util.lookup.implspi.ActiveQueue reportError
WARNING: Cannot hack ReferenceQueue to fix bug #206621!
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.openide.util.lookup.implspi.ActiveQueue$Impl cannot access a member of class java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue (in module java.base) with modifiers "private"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkAccess(Field.java:1074)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:415)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.implspi.ActiveQueue$Impl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.implspi.ActiveQueue.queue(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup.activeQueue(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup.access$600(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup$ReferenceToResult.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup$ReferenceToResult.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.AbstractLookup.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.Lookup.lookupResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.openide.util.Lookup.lookupAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader.allCLIs(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.CLIHandler.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.MainImpl.main(Unknown Source)
    at org.netbeans.Main.main(Unknown Source)

t@tsu:~/src/edk2$
```

Comment: What's the output of `which java`, `update-alternatives --display java`, and `java -version`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial that you followed to install NetBeans 8.1 is obsolete. Current versions of NetBeans require openjdk-8-jdk, not openjdk-6-jdk or openjdk-7-jdk as recommended in the tutorial. Uninstall openjdk-6-jdk and openjdk-7-jdk if you don't need them, and install openjdk-8-jdk using the following command:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Hopefully installing openjdk-6-jdk/openjdk-7-jdk didn't permanently mess up your Java path and you can get started using NetBeans immediately.

The version of NetBeans from the default Ubuntu repositories is 10.0 in Ubuntu 18.04 and later.

Comment: thanks I actually never forget the JDK i alrady had followed another guide on this and whas even one-up. i had oracle's version 9 (which doesn't cause conflict does it?)

Comment: Oracle's version 9 does conflict with NetBeans 8 which I found out the hard way. JDK 9 is a development version, not yet a stable release. In addition to that problem I had a hard time resetting the Java path back to the default after I uninstalled JDK 9 and installed JDK 8. I hope the same thing doesn't happen to you. There was no answer for this issue on Ask Ubuntu, but I found an answer that worked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: As i Said I shy away from openJDK and you should too. :) It really is a hornet's nest of issues compared to oracle's closed jdk

Comment: use this : http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html run `sudo gedit /etc/environment` add `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"` save and run `source /etc/environment` and you're set

Answer (score -1):

Try some other IDE that are native to Linux World such as Geany instead of 
NetBeans.

see this link to install `open-jdk`.
[How to compile a .java file on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145748/how-to-compile-a-java-file-on-ubuntu)

after that simply you can use Gedit to code and `javac` command in terminal
as java compiler.