# Running java applets in the browser

Tags: java, browser, applet, jre

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

With my 12.04, if I point my browser (either firefox or chrome) to
    http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp
it will say that java is not working.

After a `sudo apt-get install default-jre` the problem persists.

What is the "ubuntu way" to have the java applets run?

Comment: Make sure you install Sun Java.  Java.com won't read other versions as well.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java for details about the various versions of Java, and then follow installation procedures.