# how can istall installtion jre-7u5-linux-x64 JAVA on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

I want to install jre-7u5-linux-x64 on Ubuntu 12.04

```
marwa@marwa-Vostro-1540:~$ sudo apt-get install  
[sudo] password for marwa: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package jre1.7.0_05
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'jre1.7.0_05'

marwa@marwa-Vostro-1540:~$ sudo gedit etc/apt/sources.list
```

But the gedit is empty, what i can do?

And what is the meaning of :

```
Reading package lists... Done`
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package jre1.7.0_05
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'jre1.7.0_05'
```

Answer (score 3):

> `sudo gedit etc/apt/sources.list`

This command is **wrong**. The file path should begin with "/":

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you need java (jre or jdk), you can install it using [user827992's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/164461/5538) or using Ubuntu software center, typing "java" in the search box, select the package and click "Install":
[image: ubuntu software center 12.04 java jre]

Answer (score 2):

Most things will work fine with OpenJDK7 but if you are running into one of the exceptions the easiest way to install JRE7 is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

The page that gives detailed instructions is [Here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html).

Source: http://www.webupd8.org

Quote from source page:

> If you really need to use Oracle (ex Sun) Java instead of OpenJDK in Ubuntu, here's an easy way to do it: **a PPA repository to install and keep your computer up to date with the latest Oracle Java 7 (Java JDK which includes JRE).**

The PPA installed with the above command does not actually contain Oracle Java. ** Oracle licenses no longer allow Java to be redistributed.** This PPA works by connecting to Oracles official download server and downloads the file, it is then installed by `apt-get` or can be installed by the Ubuntu Software Center.  It works the same way that the Flash Pluging installer works.  Here is what the PPA manager(which is also the soure of these directions, see [this link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html)(same link as above)) here is some more of the page pasted here.

> **Oracle JDK7 itself is not hosted in the PPA** because that's not allowed by the new Java license (which is also the reason why it has been removed from the official Ubuntu repositories); **the package in the PPA automatically downloads (and installs) Oracle Java JDK 7 from its official website and installs it on your computer**, just like the flashplugin-installer package does.

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Comment: i did what u say that i use

Comment: what u say but i have these lines in terminal Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|62.41.4.202|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 81439763 (78M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: `jdk-7u5-linux-x64.tar.gz'

     0K ........ . ........'' so what should i do after that &what ok mean????

Comment: I edited my answer to better explain, I don't want to cut and paste any more from the source website, I may end up using more that would be allowed, so if you still need more information please check the link I provided.  I am not trying to be arrogant here, but I don't want to plagiarize webup8.org, or otherwise take credit for their work, so my best option is to refer you to their page if I have not been clear enough.

Comment: sorry it forgot to include this in my last comment, the "OK ... ..." is just a progress bar for the download so that you know that is it still running and it will give you occasional size updates as well.  "......... 20kb" ".......30kb""....40kb" , until it has completely downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

To install java in your machine follow these steps. This documentation cover installation and enabling java for browser. Download `jre-7u5-linux-x64`. Put it in Downloads folder.

- Open a terminal. **Copy/Paste** to remove any prior installation of java.

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge openjdk-\*
  ```
- Make directory in `/usr/local/java` where this software will install.

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/java
  ```
- Now copy `jre-7u5-linux-x64.tar.gz` into `/usr/local/java` directory.

  ```
  sudo -s cp -r ~/Downloads/jre-7u5-linux-x64.tar.gz /usr/local/java
  ```
- Now change directory to `/usr/local/java`

  ```
  cd /usr/local/java
  ```
- Change your file permission and extract by typing

  ```
  sudo -s chmod a+x jre-7u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
  sudo -s tar xvzf jre-7u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
  ```
- Now open `/etc/profile` file: `gksudo gedit /etc/profile` and copy paste below text at the last of the recent opened file.

  ```
  JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_05
  PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
  export JAVA_HOME
  export PATH
  ```
- Now tell your system that you have newly java installed and use it from my installed directory.

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_05/bin/java" 1
  sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_05/bin/java
  ```
- Reload system profile so that it can use java.

  ```
  . /etc/profile
  ```
- Now reboot your system.
- Verify that your java is working in [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp)
- Now install java plugin for you browser (Firefox & Chrome).

### Chrome

```
cd /opt/google/chrome/plugins
sudo ln -s /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_05/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
```

### Firefox

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
cd /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
sudo ln -s /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_05/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
java -version % this will give you what java do you have.
```

Comment: Can this work also for Mathematica? Should I follow similar steps?

Answer (score 1):

First be sure that your apt cache is up to date with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you want to search a package with a particular word in it like `jre`, just run

```
apt-cache search jre
```

in a terminal to get the list of all the available packages in the repository.

You can install the package that you want with

```
sudo apt-get install packageName
```