# java installation on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Can you please help me install java on buntu 12.04 please explain to me as someone who never used ubuntu in his entire life step by step with pictures if possible. i am new to this OS & many advisers start just in the middle whereas new users don't even know how to get to other parts I am using 32 bit & installed ubuntu 12.04.