# I can't find or run downloaded Geogebra

Tags: java

I can't find it. I can't run it. I have no idea what to do now that it's on my computer. I'm new at this stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I went to http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/download and selected the Web Start. Firefox asked me how I wanted to run the file and I selected Ice Tea Java (that's OpenJDK 6 in the software center).

After that it downloaded some stuff in a window and then loaded. And it put an icon on my desktop. I'm good to go.

---

In short: Install Java and use the web start.

- [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Answer (score -2):

Seems to me you did not extract it correctly.

Try this if you already didn't.

- Download it again
- Use archive manager to extract it.
- When it asks you to to extract, extract it to downloads.
- Open the folder
- Find a `.exe` file of possible and your done.

If you did not find any executable distribution of any kind then run

```
sudo -apt install "file.exe"
```

if that does not help contact me again if you will.