# How do I install ia32-libs so I can run yWorks diagrams in Ubuntu 11.10 64bit?

Tags: 11.10, installation

I'm a beginner here. Step by step near plain english would be appreciated if you have an answer. Thanks

Comment: Isn't it [Java](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java) rather than the 32-bit libs you need for yEd?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> and paste the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

First command is only needed if your package index files are not updated. Anyway it is good idea to run it.