# How do I install Oracle Java on 12.04 such that it works in Google Chrome/Chromium?

Tags: java, google-chrome, chromium, openjdk

I've looked at the other questions asked on this subject and I got OpenJDK and its plugin for web browsers but it isn't working for me. Please help me here, would be much appreciated if someone could give me a series of commands to write into terminal to install it.

Comment: I found this guide very useful for installing Oracle JDK 7 http://thedaneshproject.com/posts/how-to-install-java-7-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

Comment: Is this the stuff you tried? http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java

Comment: If you have all openjdk updates applied, it should work with the Chromium/Chrome in 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is now irrelevant as Chrome no longer supports Java beyond version 35.

Comment: Chrome(ium) no longer support *NPAPI* plugins (in Linux) beyond version 35. Until there is a PPAPI plugin for Java, it cannot be used in Chrome(ium).