# How to install Java Plug-in?

Tags: 10.04, java, plugins, webex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

WebEx complains that Java is NOT working and that the plug-in needs to be enabled, but the plug-in is not in Tools > Add-ons. `Search all add-ons` and `Ubuntu Software Center` are not able to find the Java plug-in for Firefox. How is the Java Plug-in for  Firefox installed on Ubuntu 10.04, or is there a workaround for installing WebEx?

Comment: These solutions should help you install Java (Oracle or not) in to your computer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java