# How do i install chrome and java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

I have used google for two hours now. Could someone please just write down what i need to enter to install both chrome and java. I am using ubuntu 64 bit and i am new to all of this and finding it rather hard to do anything.

Comment: And here for chrome: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/

Comment: Next time don't waste so much time, ask us first, we'll save you time!