# Cannot get Java to work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, java, opera, jre, firefox-extensions

In Firefox 17 on [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin), I cannot get the [Java verification applet](http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre) to work (needless to say, I cannot get any Java applications on the browser working).

I already tried uninstalling and re-installing the [AFAIK](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAIK) necessary components ([screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vYxy.png), [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyQrm.png)) (before, I had Java 6 AND 7 installed. I already tried leaving only Java 7, and now I am back to leaving only Java 6), but I cannot get it to work.

**How do I get [JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine#Java_Runtime_Environment_from_Oracle) up and running in Firefox?**

**UPDATE:** I had so much trouble with Java in Firefox quitting working after upgrades, etc. that I gave up on Firefox entirely (my main purpose of using this Ubuntu machine is to safely run Java applications away from my main computer). I now run [Opera](http://www.opera.com/download/linux/) and never had any problems again - it comes with Java, and it just works.

Comment: Are you certain that no applets work? I can't get the verification applet to run but I can get other applets to work, such as the [ShapeMover example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/user.html) in the Java Tutorial.

Comment: All I ran was `sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin` and all applets that I've tried have worked except the verification applet you mentioned.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm running Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Spencer, I dont know when it started working, but the applet I needed to run is working, eventhough the test applet does not. Since I was checking to see if it was working using the damn test applet, I was still under the impression it wasn't working. It must have gotten fixed during my uninstall-reinstall ordeal. Thank you. Feel free to submit an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the Java verification applet doesn't work with the implementation of Java that Ubuntu uses ([OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/)), but other applets should work if you install the Java web plugin, which is a plugin that lets Java applets run in a web browser.

According to the [community documentation for Java](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java),

> #### Browser plugin
>
> 1. Install the `icedtea6-plugin` package using any installation method.
> 2. Install the `icedtea-7-plugin` package using any installation method.

If you are using or want to use the default version of Java included with Ubuntu, just run

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```

If you want to use a specific version, just use the packages listed above.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/223420/cannot-get-java-to-work-in-firefox#comment275860_223420

Comment: I have icedtea installed already and applets are not loading for me unfortunately

Answer (score 4):

You need the browser plugin for Java to work in Firefox.

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-plugin
```

Then `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Check which version is activated: `java -version`

Install the icedtea-web plugin if not yet installed: `sudo apt-get install icedtea-web`

Comment: I already had it, but naturally you weren't aware of that because I was editing the answer to include info on what I already had installed (which took me a while, because I cannot post images/more than 2 hyperlinks/etc).

I wish SE checked your network reputation and instantly gave old members with more than X points on a network site 10, instead of 1 point, to start. But that's a suggestion for _Meta_.

Comment: See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/88058/27968

Comment: i reinstalled openJDK7, and now I have both installed, like I did before. I restarted firefox but no go on the verification applet.

Comment: Thank you, see comment http://askubuntu.com/questions/223420/cannot-get-java-to-work-in-firefox#comment275860_223420 above