# Installation of a second Java SDK

Tags: java, jdk, jre

I have Java sdk 1.7 installed correctly. It turns out I need the version of 1.6 also (an application needs it).

How do I install the version of 1.6 and how do I make sure that we'll both work correctly eventually?

Comment: How's this possible? Latest version won't support previous version's compatibility!! Which application? Can you provide that message here?

Comment: I can't, you don't need to know the name of the application, it won't help you at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is fully backwards compatible, you can see it by the version numbers. JAVA 6 and 7 are really 1.6 and 1.7 so you only needs the latest version installed.

You may need more packages than waht are provided in the SDK, check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/48472/10698) for more help.

Following old tutorials runs the risk of not being able to follow them since they don't work anymore. This tutorial you are following is four years old(2009), and the fix for it is a year old which may have worked when 1.7 Was just released but now it's just a memory berried in the history of software development.

Find a new tutorial on the topic, since this one is dead.

OR you can go the extra mile an install a VM with Ubuntu 10.04 and Java sdk 1.6 if you think it's worth that much work...

Comment: do I install 1.6 version exactly the way I did for 1.7?

Comment: No you only install Java 1.7 it's fully backwards compatible so you don't need two versions as I said.

Comment: I need -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707016/error-when-running-sbt-install-emulator

Comment: @AlanDert On the top of the article it says "Note: this article hasn't been updated in a while and is out of date. In doubt refer to the README of the sbt-android-plugin." And the article is from 2009, so this is so outdated it can be. 1.7 is the standard version and you need to find an up to date article instead.

Comment: but it also says about downgrading back 1.6 and that it helps.

Comment: @AlanDert this question was written when 1.7 was just released, it's not viable right now. You need to find a new tutorial since the one you are following are four years old!