# ./configure no such file or directory even after installing build essentials

Tags: bash, java

I'm trying to install Java SE 7 on my ubuntu 13.04.

I have already downloaded tar.gz file and extracted.

But when I wrote in terminal:

```
./configure
```

I saw this message

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I see it even after installing build essentials package.

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Java SE is a binary package, so it should be installed in [the other way](http://askubuntu.com/a/88058/171636) than source packages.

Answer (score 7):

You only run the ./configure command when building certain applications from source.

The Java installation files that you have downloaded aren't source code they are precompiled binaries. For instructions on how to install Java take a look at the page on the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) as this has several different options.

I recomend using the option titled 'Using webupd8.org's strikingly simple method.' as it will integrate the installation of Java with your package manaement system and automatically keep it up to date along with the rerst of your system.

Answer (score 1):

**Preamble**

The reason why you are getting the "bash: ./configure: No such file or directory" is because you are not in the right directory where the downloaded file you are about to install is located.

**To fix that**

(a.) FOLLOWING README INSTRUCTION

1. Locate where your downloaded Java tar.gz file.
2. Extract the file by right-clicking on it and select 'Extract Here'.
3. Look for the 'Readme text' file and open it.
4. Follow the instruction on how to install the file in the Readme text(installation of tar.gz file can be different from normal commands used to do installation of files in Ubuntu).

(b.) USING GENERAL COMMANDS

1. Open the terminal by pressing  *CTRL + ALT +T*.
2. Type  *tar -zxvf .tar.gz* .
3. Type  *sudo su*  and enter your root password.
4. type  *cd and add the path of your downloaded file* . If you do not know the path of the downloaded file type  *ls -a*  to list all the directories and locate your file directory.
5. Type  *./configure*  and press ENTER key
6. Type  *make*  and press ENTER key.
7. Type  *make install*  and press ENTER key.

(c) USING THE UBUNTU SOFTWARE CENTER

1. Open Ubuntu Software Center
2. Type java in the search
3. Look for Java SE 7 and click 'install' to install it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem.  The short answer is you have to type `./configure --prefix=/your/chosen/directory` when inside the unpacked `.tar.gz` file directory.  That is where the `configure` file is.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me while installing samba domain controller and You may downloaded the package like me as below: (The commands are related to samba installation!!)

```
git clone -b v4-5-stable git://git.samba.org/samba.git
```

and you are in folder say (ex: folder1) and when you type

(ex: `./configure --enable-debug --enable-selftest`)

it bring up an error

> bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

So here I had to go inside the samba folder in the folder1

/home/ubuntu/folder1/samba#
I know it is very late answer but this may help :)