# bash: ./configure no such file or directory even after installing build essentials

Tags: bash, software-installation, gambas3

I'm trying to install gambas 3.0.0. I download the the file gambas3-3.0.0.tar.bz2 from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gambas/files/gambas3/gambas3-3.0.0.tar.bz2/download) and i follow every step from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/324261/configure-no-such-file-or-directory-even-after-installing-build-essentials) but i still get the same error
`bash: ./confugure: No such file or directory`

I'm not sure if it's important but I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on Parallels Desktop (Virtual machine in a mac)

Comment: The steps you are trying to follow are for Java SE, not Gambas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`./configure` would be a local script (hence the `./` - which means "in the current directory") - if there is such a file, it's something that would be provided by the software you are trying to build, not by a system package.

In this case, the `gambas3-3.0.0.tar.bz2` tarball doesn't contain such a script, but it does contain a `configure.ac` file. That means that you need to go back one step, and generate the `configure` script from the `configure.ac` script using `autoconf`.

The tarball appears to provide two additional autoconf wrapper scripts called `reconf` and `reconf-all` - I don't *know* which you should use, but I'd guess there's no harm in going the whole hog and running the latter. So the full sequence of commands becomes:

```
./reconf-all
./configure
make
```

followed by `sudo make install` if everything is successful and you want to go ahead and install the software in the default locations (usually `/usr/local` for this kind of installation).