# Why can't I install this package?

Tags: command-line, java

when i type in `java` or `javac` it tells me

```
the program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
```

I'll put in a screen shot, but when I type the command

```
sudo apt-install <selected package>
```

it will do nothing :/

Help is very much appreciated.  You can find the picture of the Terminal here: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've spelled `defult-jre`, when it's supposed to be `default-jre`.

If you use the middle click on your mouse (mouse wheel button), you will paste the last marked text. So if you mark a package name and type `sudo apt-get install` (mouse wheel click), it will be correctly spelled.

Also using tab will ensure that it's correctly spelled.

Related:

- [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/q/56104/10698)
- [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/q/48468/10698)

Comment: figures, thank you for the help i think i got it working now.