# installing java in ubuntu

Tags: java

this is my first time using linux ubuntu. 
I'm trying to install java, i downloaded the file from the java website, extracted the file to the desktop and the extracted file's name now is jre1.7.0_45

i'm following this to install the java
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Java-on-Ubuntu

but omg i can't even get past number 2.
i get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-7-jre
```

how can i do this please?

Comment: have you ran `sudo apt-get update`  ???

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden i didn't, what is that for?

Comment: ah ok i see whats it for, and then after i run that? do i run the `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre` ?

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running? And please clarify, do you want to install OpenJDK or Oracle Java?

Comment: Yes, try running that command and see if it works now. That is if you're running ubuntu 12.04 or higher

Comment: If you're running a version lower that 12.04 you'll need to download it manually and install it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471564/installing-openjdk-7-jre-on-ubuntu-10-04-package-openjdk-7-jre-has-no-installa

Comment: Also read the answers to the question: [How do I install Java?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java).

Comment: @xangua Ubuntu 13. and on the java, i just clicked  the 64 version on the website, when i extracted it i think the file was jre1.....

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden ok i'll try this and let you know what happens

Comment: @ArnovanderWeijden when i run `sudo apt-get update` it says `E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)` and
`E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`

Comment: I read in the other comments that you were successful in installing flash.
If you still want to resolve this problem your describing above comment and I'll help but I believe you're using the ubuntu software center or are using something else so a reboot should suffice if closing everything does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a PPA and install(and recieve updates) the latest Oracle Java 7 in Ubuntu (supports Ubuntu 13.10, 13.04, 12.10, 12.04 and 10.04) use the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

**Source** http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Comment: Could you explain the commands you wrote? I know an explanation is in the link but if the link breaks then there isn't one anymore. So please explain the commands in the answer. You can add the explanation below. Just describe what each command do, and why you need to do it perhaps.

Comment: wow great it's installing now, i'll update in a minute once its done! :)