# How do I set up Java path?

Tags: java

I want to set up Java in my PC running Ubuntu 12.4 LTS with 64 bit architecture. I followed different posts on this site to do the same but I am confused, whilst I try to navigate to usr/lib/jvm I see a lot of folders at this point. Which one to set as path? I have attached  a screen shot to explain my issue:

[image]

**EDIT:** I have java installed but I am stuck at setting the Home for Java. I executed Java -version on my terminal and I had the following output:

```
root@pc-dev-a147:/# java -version
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
root@pc-dev-a147:/#
```

**EDIT:** 
I think I solved the problem. These are the steps I took to gain the know how of how to do it:

1) [To check if I have Java or I have to install it.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

2) [What does this mysterious  HOME enviornment variable do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102022/what-does-the-java-home-environment-variable-do)

3) [Finally how to locate and set the variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655641/set-environment-variable-in-ubuntu)

Now if I do `echo $JAVA_HOME` I get:

```
root@pc-dev-a147:/home/Johndoe/Downloads/Softwares/FlashTool# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk
root@pc-dev-a147:/home/junaid/Downloads/Softwares/FlashTool#
```

However I am stuck in a different issue now which is explained [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/696558/wrong-oem-while-trying-to-use-flashtool-android-rooting?noredirect=1#comment886502_696558)

Comment: WHat after whereis? It gives me something like: `java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/lib/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz`. So do I need to take any further action? Sorry I am new to Ubuntu, please bear with me.

Comment: How did you installed Java? Also, don't java appears when you type `java -version`?

Comment: For some reason I don't remember how I installed Java.