# Android sdk manager permission denied

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am setting up eclipse and ADT everything is working fine JAVA, android virtual devices and everything except the **ADT sdk manager** it says permission denied.

```
/home/yousaf/android-sdks/tools/android: 84: java: Permission denied
/home/yousaf/android-sdks/tools/android: 101: java: Permission denied
exec: 114: java: Permission denied
```

I have executable permission on this folder and files owner is my own user and I have tried to run this as root but same results.

**Here are the permissions for that file**

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 yousaf yousaf 3498 2014-01-07 13:27 /home/yousaf/android-sdks/tools/android
```

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -l /home/yousaf/android-sdks/tools/android`

Comment: @wilf i have added the output of what you said can please look into this ?

Comment: Errr... Isn't hat is `ls -l...` output for the parent directory? Make sure java is installed - see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java). Running `chmod -R +x /home/yousaf/android-sdks/tools/android` may help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem and following way i resolve it.
you should use command line for updating **SDK**

use following commoand.

go to [ADT bundle]/sdk/tools folder. by

```
cd /home/yousaf/android-sdks/tools/
```

then

```
 android update sdk
```

this resolve my problem.