# New User - Installing .jar File Difficulty

Tags: java

New Ubuntu User - trying to download and install a file... in this case a .jar file... and having difficulty knowing where to install it.

I have used Software Center to install .exe files, and it is so easy and nice. But the .jar is not handled the same way for some reason... maybe because it requires Java?

What is the easiest/most direct way to download and install a file in Ubuntu when Software Center is not handling it for you?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you please tell what kind of programm needs you to install as a jar-file?

Answer (score 2):

When you are given a `.jar` file, it needs to be run using your Java installation.

For example

```
java -jar minecraft.jar
```

If you do not have java, you can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Comment: There is also [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java) on installing Java...