# I can't log in after I inserted some variables in my environment file

Tags: environment-variables

I installed 12.04. Yesterday I tried installing tomcat server and java. There was some errors in that installation and when I tried to open my system after some time I couldn't login. At that time I found its in loop. When I used terminal using ctrl+alt+<kbd>f1</kbd>. I can login there, and after login there shows one error which I incurred while installing java.

it shows like in 31 line.

```
Syntax error near unexpected token '('
```

and also in line

```
export JAVA_HOME=/media/F25ACC3E5ACBFCFB/Program Files (x86)/Java
```

Comment: Can you paste the error to your question?

Comment: it shows like in 31 line..syntax error near unexpected token '(' and also in line 'export JAVA_HOME=/media/F25ACC3E5ACBFCFB/Program Files (x86)/Java'

Comment: Please post the **exact** error message, as it is. It is difficult to make out from just a part of the error message.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to link the path to Java binaries you have installed on windows to ubuntu. This won't work. You need to install Java on ubuntu and export the path as `JAVA_HOME`. Refer this to see how to install java: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Wont work in this case. In this case, the problem is with a file the OP edited himself, not a Xauthority file or similar.

Comment: @jobin and @ avinash raj..grateful to ur comments. when i login via ctrl+alt+f1..my error report is like this    -bash: /etc/profile: line 31:syntax error near unexpected token '('      and    second error  -bash: /etc/profile:line 31:'export JAVA_HOME=/media/F25ACC3E5ACBFCFB/Program Files (x86)/Java'

Comment: only i need to solve this problem and delete those installed java and again get back to old state..all i have done coz f my foolishness..please hit me with a solution to get back to working stage.thanx

Comment: @AvinashRaj this is not a duplicated

Answer (score 1):

1. Login via Ctrl+Alt+F1.
2. Run this command:

   ```
   nano "$(grep -l 'export JAVA_HOME=/media/F25ACC3E5ACBFCFB/Program Files (x86)/Java' ~/* 2>/dev/null | head -n1 | tr -d '\n')"
   ```
3. Delete this line (should be at or near line 31):

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/media/F25ACC3E5ACBFCFB/Program Files (x86)/Java
   ```
4. Save and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Login should now work.

For how to install Java correctly, see [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/a/88058/176889).

Answer (score -1):

Try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> To open terminal and run this command:

```
rm- rf .gnome .gnome2 .gncof .gconfd .metacity
```

This will reset some gnome settings and login should work. Let me know if it works.