# Problem Opening Programs and Where is what I intall?

Tags: command-line, java, minecraft

I download Java to run Minecraft and also other programs that need installation. When I open it, instead of opening it with an installation or something it opens the folders inside of the program with the Archive Manager. I tried to open it with Wine but JAVA for example is .tar.gz.

The other problem I got is that when I install a program from terminal I cannot find it (I've tried searching it) and also I can't use it, for example Unrar.

I am new to this software. I would be very thanks full if you help me.

Comment: I think you have got source code.you will have to build it and then install .search google for how to install java from source

Comment: also what output you are getting while installing a program from terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When installing new software you should use either the Ubuntu Software Center or `sudo apt-get install <applicationNameHere>`.  If you are downloading tars or zips, you are going to have a harder time finding/running them.

As for Java and Minecraft, run the following command from the Terminal:

```
java -version
```

Does it return your current version of Java?  Or does it reply with `command not found`?  It should return output similar to this:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

If it returns `command not found` then you will need to follow the steps listed in this question to install Java: [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Once you have done that and are getting correct output from running a `java -version`, then you can download Minecraft from here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar

Minecraft (for Linux) comes delivered in a Java ARchive or JAR file.  You can run this using Java.  First, copy Minecraft.jar from your `~/Downloads` directory to another location.  I created a "minecraft" directory under my home directory for this purpose:

```
cd ~
mkdir minecraft
cd minecraft
mv ../Downloads/Minecraft.jar .
```

To run Minecraft, (in the future) just change to that directory and invoke it with Java:

```
cd ~/minecraft
java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

Remember, Ubuntu (Linux) is case-sensitive, so make sure you don't alter the case of any of these commands.  You can also do other things like give Minecraft (Java) more memory, or create a clickable desktop icon, but this should be enough to get you started.