# I can't log in on partypokers website why is that?

Tags: firefox

long time user first time question asker. I am an avid online poker player,but for some reason cannot play my site of chioce within the browser with ubuntu. I can do it with my windows machine,but not my ubuntu.
I have tried opera, firefox, chrome, chromium all to no avail,every time the login screen is missing/blank. I have all permissions set and up to date java.Does anyone else know how to fix this or have this problem ? I have supplied the link to the site as this is not a link share promotion or anything,i just want to be able to play,i tried to post screen shots but said i need 10 reputation

http://www.partypoker.com/play-now.html

Comment: upload your picture to any image site like http://imgur.com/ and we can add it in the question, the reason for the 10 rep cap is to reduce spam.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've missed to install java for the browser. you can install it by this link [here.](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/icedtea6-plugin/)

or installing it via the terminal by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea6-plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

If the website requires Flash, run the following into a terminal to fix it for you :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

if it requires Java plugins; have a look to the following [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java))

for a more comprehensive plugin installation guide; check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxPlugins

Comment: but chrome and chromium comes with flash pre-installed...

Comment: The site requires java.