# Error running Java web application with OpenJDK Java7 runtime in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: firefox, 14.04, java, openjdk, icedtea

I have fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install on my HP Pavilion g6 laptop.

I have installed **OpenJDK** and **IcedTea** plugin in order to run Java applications as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java).

But when I am going to **chess.com** website and select *play against computer* option it is showing an error. "Click here for details an exception has occurred"

[image]

Then I ran firefox from terminal and opened Java application again. Terminal output is like

```
bibi@bibi-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ firefox

 (process:32619): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion
 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

 java version "1.7.0_55" OpenJDK Runtime
 Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1) OpenJDK 64-Bit
 Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode) No permission to use the
 keyboard API for http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net
 java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 http://www.chess.com/play/ChessApplet.1.14.18.jar  at
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1673)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1671)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1244)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.HttpUtils.consumeAndCloseConnection(HttpUtils.java:66)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.HttpUtils.consumeAndCloseConnectionSilently(HttpUtils.java:52)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.getUrlResponseCodeWithRedirectonResult(ResourceTracker.java:907)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.findBestUrl(ResourceTracker.java:955)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.initializeResource(ResourceTracker.java:788)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.processResource(ResourceTracker.java:628)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.access$600(ResourceTracker.java:79)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker$Downloader$1.run(ResourceTracker.java:1235)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker$Downloader$1.run(ResourceTracker.java:1233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker$Downloader.run(ResourceTracker.java:1233)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
 java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 http://www.chess.com/play/ChessApplet.1.14.18.jar  at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
    at
 java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.getUrlResponseCodeWithRedirectonResult(ResourceTracker.java:903)
    ... 9 more

 java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 http://www.chess.com/play/ChessApplet.1.14.18.jar  at
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1673)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1671)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1244)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.HttpUtils.consumeAndCloseConnection(HttpUtils.java:66)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.HttpUtils.consumeAndCloseConnectionSilently(HttpUtils.java:52)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.getUrlResponseCodeWithRedirectonResult(ResourceTracker.java:907)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.findBestUrl(ResourceTracker.java:955)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.initializeResource(ResourceTracker.java:788)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.processResource(ResourceTracker.java:628)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.access$600(ResourceTracker.java:79)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker$Downloader$1.run(ResourceTracker.java:1235)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker$Downloader$1.run(ResourceTracker.java:1233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker$Downloader.run(ResourceTracker.java:1233)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
 java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 http://www.chess.com/play/ChessApplet.1.14.18.jar  at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
    at
 java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.getUrlResponseCodeWithRedirectonResult(ResourceTracker.java:903)
    ... 9 more

 No permission to use the keyboard API for
 http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 http://www.chess.com/play/ChessApplet.1.14.18.jar  at
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1673)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1671)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1244)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.HttpUtils.consumeAndCloseConnection(HttpUtils.java:66)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.HttpUtils.consumeAndCloseConnectionSilently(HttpUtils.java:52)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.getUrlResponseCodeWithRedirectonResult(ResourceTracker.java:907)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.findBestUrl(ResourceTracker.java:955)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.initializeResource(ResourceTracker.java:788)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.processResource(ResourceTracker.java:628)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.access$600(ResourceTracker.java:79)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker$Downloader$1.run(ResourceTracker.java:1235)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker$Downloader$1.run(ResourceTracker.java:1233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker$Downloader.run(ResourceTracker.java:1233)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
 java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 http://www.chess.com/play/ChessApplet.1.14.18.jar  at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
    at
 java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.getUrlResponseCodeWithRedirectonResult(ResourceTracker.java:903)
    ... 9 more

 java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 http://www.chess.com/play/ChessApplet.1.14.18.jar  at
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at
 sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1673)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1671)
    at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1244)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.HttpUtils.consumeAndCloseConnection(HttpUtils.java:66)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.HttpUtils.consumeAndCloseConnectionSilently(HttpUtils.java:52)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.getUrlResponseCodeWithRedirectonResult(ResourceTracker.java:907)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.findBestUrl(ResourceTracker.java:955)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.initializeResource(ResourceTracker.java:788)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.processResource(ResourceTracker.java:628)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.access$600(ResourceTracker.java:79)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker$Downloader$1.run(ResourceTracker.java:1235)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker$Downloader$1.run(ResourceTracker.java:1233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker$Downloader.run(ResourceTracker.java:1233)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
 java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 http://www.chess.com/play/ChessApplet.1.14.18.jar  at
 sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1624)
    at
 java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.cache.ResourceTracker.getUrlResponseCodeWithRedirectonResult(ResourceTracker.java:903)
    ... 9 more

 Attempted to download
 http://www.chess.com/play/ChessApplet.1.14.18.jar, but failed to
 connect! JAR http://www.chess.com/play/ChessApplet.1.14.18.jar not
 found. Continuing. JAR
 http://www.chess.com/play/ChessApplet.1.14.18.jar not found.
 Continuing. netx: Initialization Error: Could not initialize applet.
 (Fatal: Initialization Error: Unknown Main-Class. Could not determine
 the main class for this application.) netx: Initialization Error:
 Could not initialize applet. (Fatal: Initialization Error: Unknown
 Main-Class. Could not determine the main class for this application.)
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error:
 Could not initialize applet. For more information click "more
 information button".   at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:746)  at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.getApplet(Launcher.java:675)     at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:908) Caused
 by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error:
 Unknown Main-Class. Could not determine the main class for this
 application.   at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:684)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init(JNLPClassLoader.java:277)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.createInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:351)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:418)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:394)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:711)    ...
 2 more

 net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error:
 Could not initialize applet. For more information click "more
 information button".   at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:746)  at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.getApplet(Launcher.java:675)     at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:908) Caused
 by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error:
 Unknown Main-Class. Could not determine the main class for this
 application.   at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:684)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init(JNLPClassLoader.java:277)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.createInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:351)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:418)
    at
 net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:394)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplet(Launcher.java:711)    ...
 2 more

 Error on Java side: 

 Error: Unable to fetch applet instance id from Java side.

  Error on Java side: 

  Error: Unable to fetch applet instance id from Java side.

  NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down

  NOTE: child process received `Goodbye', closing down

  bibi@bibi-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Is there any solution for this problem?
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: As the error report says, the JAR file doesn't exist. If you follow the link you'll get a 404 error page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it with OpenJDK, and I got the same problem.

[image]

Tried it with Oracle Java 8, and it works.  Try Oracle Java instead of OpenJDK.

[image]

Comment: k I will try now and return..

Comment: But I am confused..... can I follow [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre) or which instruction exactly should I folllow.. and before installing should I remove OpenJDK.

Comment: installed Oracle Java with these and that solved my issue.... '**sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java**' 
'**sudo apt-get update**' 
'**sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer**'