# JDK 8 install in ubuntu

Tags: java

I'm tring to install jdk 8 for weeks, but it fails.Following are some outputs,

sudo update-alternatives --config java

```
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /opt/java-oracle/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
```

which java

```
   /usr/bin/java
```

java

```
 bash: /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

ls -l /usr/bin/java

```
 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

ls -l /etc/alternatives/java

```
/etc/alternatives/java -> /opt/java-oracle/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
```

sudo update-alternatives --config javac

> `/opt/java-oracle/jdk1.8.0/bin/javac   1         manual mode`

javac

```
  Error: could not find libjava.so
  Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

If you can please give me a help to slove this problem. 
Thank You

Comment: openjdk 7 is in the software center, why dont you use that?

Comment: no i want to install jdk 8... I couldn't find jdk8 in software center. Is it avaiable....?

Comment: fwiw, I was looking for the oracle jdk, which can be found here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java/1051470#1051470 is probably the more useful question (it actually gives a number of solutions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I installed the jdk just fine. Here's what I did.

1. Get the **.rpm** file from [Oracle's website.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen)
2. Open up a terminal and type this command:`sudo apt-get install alien`
3. Wait for alien to install.
4. Type: `sudo alien -i -c <path to the file>`
5. Wait for that to finish installing.  It will look like it's not doing anything for a while, but it is.
6. Test the installation with: `java -version`
7. You're done!

Comment: couldn't install :     Errors were encountered while processing:
     jdk1.8.0-66
    Unable to install at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package/Deb.pm line 92,         <GETPERMS> line 1841.
     find jdk1.8.0_66-1.8.0_66 -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;
     rm -rf jdk1.8.0_66-1.8.0_66
    jprogrammer@ubuntu:~$

Answer (score 0):

I followed the suggested steps today, but was upset by the result. Mostly because installed Java was not registered in java-alternatives among other versions, and also because of apt complaining about "1 not fully installed or removed."

So I decided to provide an alternative answer.

The following steps made me happy today:

1. Get the **.tar.gz** file from [Oracle's website](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
2. Use the following command to install the package converter specific to Java: `sudo apt install java-package`
3. In the directory containing previously downloaded file, run the command: `make-jpkg jdk-8u221-linux-x64.tar.gz` (adjust the version if needed).
4. Then run: `sudo dpkg -i oracle-java8-jdk_8u221_amd64.deb` (adjust the version if needed).
5. If you have any other versions of Java installed, you may need to update alternatives: `sudo update-java-alternatives --set oracle-java8-jdk-amd64`
6. Check everything is OK: `java -version`.

Now you can delete both **.tar.gz** and **.deb** files.