# How can I install yEd graph editor on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, yed

[yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) is a feature rich editor for hierarchical diagrams and flow charts. I would like to install it on Ubuntu. Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be available in the official repositories.

What steps would I have to follow to install yEd on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two ways to install yEd on Ubuntu.

**Using the provided graphical installer**

yEd comes with an easy-to-use graphical installer that takes care of all the system dependencies (Java, most importantly):

[image: yEd installer GUI]

Follow these steps:

1. Find the *yEd Graph Editor* section on the [yworks](http://www.yworks.com/en/downloads.html) download page
2. Download the appropriate Linux yEd installer for your system (32- or 64-bit)
3. Make the installer executable with `chmod +x yEd<...>.sh` or by going into the properties menu of your file manager (*Properties → Permissions → Allow executing file as program*)
4. Run the installer and follow the outlined steps
5. When you're done you should be able to find yEd in your Unity Dash

**Manual installation**

1. [Make sure you have the latest Java release installed](https://askubuntu.com/q/48468)
2. Download the zipped yEd release on [its download page](http://www.yworks.com/en/downloads.html)
3. Extract the contents of the zipfile
4. Navigate to the extracted folder and open `yed.jar` in java:

   ```
   java -jar "yed.jar"
   ```
5. To integrate yEd into your system you can create a `.desktop` launcher under `~/.local/share/applications`. E.g.:

   ```
   $ cat ~/.local/share/applications/yed.desktop
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Name=yEd Graph Editor
   Comment=Edit graphml files in yed
   Exec=java -jar /home/user/applications/yEd/yed.jar %u
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=/home/user/applications/yEd/icons/yicon32.png
   Categories=Application;Office
   StartupNotify=false
   MimeType=application/xml;
   NoDisplay=false
   ```

   Make sure to change the `Exec=` and `Icon=` lines according to your system.

Comment: there is no PPA?

Comment: @becko The license forbids distribution, so it's not possible (unless they decide to change the license).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to associate yEd's .graphml files (it's not done automatically by the installer), you can use the following script:

```bash
#! /bin/bash

# Run the script in the root of yEd installation directory
# Tested with Ubuntu 18.04
# Tested with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS


# Create a new mime type definition file
cat >graphml+xml-mime.xml << EOL
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
   <mime-type type="application/x-graphml+xml">  
   <comment>yEd graphml file (xml format)</comment>
   <glob pattern="*.graphml"/>
   <generic-icon name="x-application-graphml+xml"/>
  </mime-type>
 </mime-info>
EOL

# Install the new mime definition
sudo xdg-mime install graphml+xml-mime.xml

# Install icon (size 48 can be extracted from i4j_extf_2_1aawyej_k3n8ea.ico file)
sudo xdg-icon-resource install --context mimetypes --size 32 .install4j/yEd.png x-application-graphml+xml

# Append %F to yEd .desktop file so it is visible in "Open With Other Application" menu
sed -i '/Exec/ s/$/ %F/' ~/.local/share/applications/yEd\ Graph\ Editor-0.desktop

# Finally go to file manager, right click, select "Open With Other Application",
# click "View All Applications" and select yEd.
```