# SIGBUS error with JRE when using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk, jre

I encountered a SIGBUS error when starting up eclipse. There was nothing wrong before this, I've just turned on the laptop and the error appears:

```
$ eclipse
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f08bd89063a, pid=4159, tid=139674439165696
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b32) (build 1.7.0_65-b32)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.3
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libzip.so+0x463a]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/alvas/hs_err_pid4159.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

**Has anyone had the same problem before? How do I resolved the problem?**

**Is it an IceTea JRE problem?** I have tried installing the latest JDK with this: [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java) but it didn't work.

The SIGBUS error in `hs_err_pid4159.log` is http://pastebin.com/w8YqFJE3

I've also tried this and it didn't work:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1072      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1072      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly resolving the problem but I've reinstalled eclipse and am using the latest version so now it's working again.

Follow installation instructions on: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-latest-eclipse-ubuntu-14-04/