# Installing java for 32 bit on a 64bit OS on terminal

Tags: 64-bit, java, 32-bit

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr 64 bit and I want to install Java 32bit.

I have removed the previous JRE which was 64 bit, now I need help how can I do this on the command line.

I was using the 64 bit version but it could not detect any audio devices when I had to attend classes online on CISCO Web-ex.

I read that I should use a 32bit JRE and a 32 bit browser. That will fix the issue.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: i was using the 64 bit version but it could not detect any audio device when i had to attend classes online on CISCO Web-ex. i read that i should use a 32bit java runtime environment and a 32 bit browser. that will fix the issue. i need help

Answer (score -2):

Your problem has solution here.

[install java](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Hope this 'll help you.