# Speech Dispatcher not working after changing voice to Festival

Tags: text-to-speech, espeak, festival

I followed [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953509/how-can-i-change-the-voice-used-by-firefox-reader-view-narrator-in-ubuntu) instructions for how to change the default voice for `spd-say` from `espeak` to `festival` hoping that would allow me to use `festival` in Chrome with a text-to-speech extension I have installed.  At first, the `spd-say` command would work fine, but the voice was barely understandable.  But after going through the above instructions, I can't get `spd-say` to work.

`echo "testing festival" | festival --tts` works, and so does `espeak "testing espeak"`, but `spd-say "testing festival"` gives me the following error:

```
Failed to connect to Speech Dispatcher:
Error: Can't connect to unix socket /run/user/1000/speech-dispatcher/speechd.sock: 
No such file or directory. Autospawn: Autospawn failed. 
Speech Dispatcher refused to start with error code, stating this as a reason:
```

What's causing this error?  I've checked both files that the above instructions said I needed to modify, and I can't see anything wrong with them.  In addition, I've uninstalled and reinstalled speech dispatcher so that the command would successfully use the `espeak` voice and then went through the instructions again, but I got the same result.

Comment: I find the link below. Install speech-dispatcher-festival package worked for me. https://groups.google.com/g/vinux-support/c/VHppxTrBwZM?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into the logfiles written by speech-dispatcher? You should be able to find them under `/run/user/1000/speech-dispatcher/log/`.

I ran into a very similar issue. In my case, I had espeak disabled and festival enabled and got the following error in `/run/user/1000/speech-dispatcher/log/speech-dispatcher.log`:

```
speechd: ERROR: Module festival failed to initialize. Reason: 
---------------
Communicating with Festival through a socket. Can't connect to Festival server. Check your configuration in etc/speech-dispatcher/modules/festival.conf for the specified host and port and check if Festival is really running there, e.g. with telnet. Please see documentation for more info.
---------------
```

I noticed that I in fact did not have festival running, which I fixed by running `systemctl enable festival` and `systemctl start festival`.

**Edit:**
Although I didn't get it to work with Firefox either, I found that `flite` is a way more stable and performant alternative to `festival` while still getting comparable audio quality.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I have not encounter the exact same problem you are describing myself, but I created a new TTS utility which help you as well. It works offline, for free with AI-based high-quality voice. You can you it everywhere: Firefox browser, PDF reader, chrome, LibreOffice, etc.

Feel free to have a look, I just created a video tutorial with installation steps and DEMO: https://youtu.be/hb1ZVwUcPCU

Download link and Project page: https://github.com/MattePalte/Verbify-TTS

Feel free to leave comment/open issue to discuss new ideas, problems or constructive criticism.

Hoping it will help you.