# How to use Firefox narrate with Mbrola

Tags: firefox, espeak

I use Firefox on Ubuntu.

I installed `espeak`.

When I use Narrate, Firefox reads a text with robotic `espeak` voices.

I installed `Mbrola` with french voices.

I can use `espeak` + `mbrola` on cli:

```
espeak -v mb/mb-fr1 "parlez vous français ?"
```

And get more realistic voices.

But firefox only uses `espeak` voice.

How to force Firefox narrate to use `Mbrola` voices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to put the Espeak/Mbrola voice by modifying the `/etc/speech-dispatcher/speechd.conf` file.

We need to Uncomment this line:

```
AddModule "espeak-mbrola-generic"    "sd_generic"   "espeak-mbrola-generic.conf"
```

And change parameter `DefaultModule` from `espeak-ng` to `espeak-mbrola-generic`

```
DefaultModule espeak-mbrola-generic
```

Comment: It's good that you could adapt the linked answer to mbrola. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To have more realistic voices with Firefox you could [use `festival`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/festival.1.html), instead of `mbrola`.
It has quite a few sets of voices available.

You could even [use festival with mbrola voices](https://www.ernstrenner.com/linux-tts-text-to-speech/#comment-230).

The interface between Firefox and `speech-dispatcher` seems not robust.
Current state of affairs may have evolved a bit, I am not able to test now.
YMMV.

**Related**:

1. [How can I change the voice used by Firefox Reader View (Narrator) in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953509/how-can-i-change-the-voice-used-by-firefox-reader-view-narrator-in-ubuntu)
2. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=237718