# How to install MaryTTS 5.2

Tags: software-installation, text-to-speech

I am trying to install MaryTTS 5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.  There is a guide on for 5.1.2 [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/709241/how-to-install-marytts-on-ubuntu)
.  However, 5.2 is way different, and I do not understand the installation [guide](https://github.com/marytts/marytts-installer) on their GitHub page.

The first command fails when executed inside the unpacked 5.2 folder:

```
marytts install:cmu-slt
--->marytts: command not found
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like just changing the file version to the current stable version would allow you to follow the other questions answer, see [MaryTTS download page](http://mary.dfki.de/download/). Essentially; download the updated [Web Installer Package](http://mary.dfki.de/download/5.2/marytts-installer-5.2.zip), change directory `cd /home/<username>/Downloads/marytts-installer-5.2`, run the web installer package `./marytts`

If You run into problems try running `./marytts` with either `--info` or `--debug`. To get either info or debug level logs. For additional information see the README.md in the install package.

Comment: I am stuck at > Building 75% > :server.  Any idea?

Comment: patients until the process throws a useful error or finishes. Or re-run the process with more verbosity, if that is possible.

Comment: I re-run and it gets stuck at 0%.  I suppose I have to delete everything and redo from the start?

Comment: @CaTx see second paragraph in edited answer. If the `info` or `debug` level logs are not sufficient try running `bash -x ./marytts`.

Comment: Starners, it's still stuck at 75%.

Comment: Could you add the output of `./marytts --debug` or the output of `bash -x ./marytts`

Comment: The debug has so many things.  This is bash output:

Comment: .......
MARY server 5.2 starting as a HTTP server...
Port 59125 already in use!
.......

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':server'.
> Process 'command '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_152/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
........
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 0.807 secs

Comment: That is after a successful installation and the server running.

Comment: Do you need me to remove everything, and redo the failed build?

Comment: If it is working no. If you are curious we could keep poking it.

Comment: I am very new to Linux.  The way things are installed are much different from Windows.  Can you explain to me why things are sometimes done this way instead of sudo apt-get?

Comment: It is mostly due to the project maintainer not wanting to package their project as a `deb`. second no community users have packaged the project as a `deb`. Packaging is a significant challenge, and the more distros you package for the harder it gets. It is much easier to write an installer script that works most of the time.

Comment: Thanks.  I will remove MaryTTS later, and walk thru the process with you.  Wanna be Linux proficient.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it partially working following this [link](https://github.com/marytts/marytts/wiki/Local-MaryTTS-Server-Installation)
.  sudo su is also needed.  Afterwards, I follow this [link](https://github.com/marytts/marytts/wiki)
 to use it.

One little thing: the sample [command](https://github.com/marytts/marytts/wiki)
 uses DE as language, and it errors out on my computer though DE is listed [locally](http://localhost:59125/locales)
.  I switched the command to [en_US](http://localhost:59125/process?INPUT_TYPE=TEXT&AUDIO=WAVE_FILE&OUTPUT_TYPE=AUDIO&LOCALE=en_US&INPUT_TEXT=%22Hallo%20Josef!%22)
, and it works.  More to be done until everything is sorted out, but for now I am happy.  Thank you very much, @J. Starnes.