# Error in software installation

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and when I want to install any software I encounter this error:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre openjdk-6-jre
[sudo] password for ali: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
 openjdk-6-jre : Depends: openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b24-1.11.1-4ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: ttf-dejavu-extra but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: icedtea-netx but it is not going to be installed
 openjdk-7-jre : Depends: openjdk-7-jre-headless (>= 7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgif4 (>= 4.1.4) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgnome2-0 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgnomevfs2-0 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgconf2-4 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk-wrapper-java-jni (>= 0.30.4-0ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Recommends: ttf-dejavu-extra but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Does it really have to be the lower versions? Because 16.04 comes with `openjdk-8` already installed? Just asking so  i can depend my answer upon.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question lies in this thread:

[How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

I know for installing older versions like you are asking there can be issues, I think this thread will solve at least the installation issues.

Comment: Lastly though, APT told you to run sudo apt-get -f install, did you?