# looking for file catalog application (GUI)

Tags: software-recommendation, files, gui

I'm looking for a Linux application to catalog the files on my many external HDs and search them. I'm using Ubuntu, so i prefer a normal deb in the repositories but i can't find one. After some research by Google, I find no proper application - does any GUI exist ?

See this old forum entry : "printable file catalog or index for (external) USB and flash drives" ( https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/printable-file-catalog-or-index-for-external-usb-and-flash-drives-829171/ ) -- here are some key texts of this page :

> Question:
>
> I'm very surprised that there is no [relatively] mature application to
> address these issues ?! Like diskettes of years past, we now
> accumulate external drives that are USB, Firewire, e-SATA, or flash.
> Unlike diskettes, these new drives hold hundreds or thousands of
> files. It is so easy (and inexpensive) to grab a drive a copy files
> that it is trivial to accumulate duplicates or more instances of the
> same files. All of this makes a catalog very valuable AND makes
> duplicate identification all the more so.
>
> Answer:
>
> It is possible that this (making a catalogue with find
> /media/Disk1 * > ~/Indices/Disk1_index ) and then searching for a
> filename in those catalogues with grep filename ~/Indices/* is so
> trivial from the command line, that no one has bothered to develop
> anything more complicated than gwhere (which seems to work, though I
> only used it the once). Duplicates are another matter altogether: Same
> filenames does not necessarily mean that the contents of those files
> are the same. Conversely, different filenames does not necessarily
> mean that the contents of the files are different.
>
> Remark:
>
> There are several *nix utilities for dealing with this sort of
> problem, fdupes comes to mind, but there are others. No application
> could compete with the method "find for indexing, grep for search"

I tried "gwhere" but it's limited and slow and its last version is of 2007. Most file catalog utilities i find are for Windows ..

Must Linux users really learn to use command line functions like "find" and "grep" to do all kinds of queries ? Eg. in a search, we often want to exclude some file types or include only images, search by date / period, etc.

Someone must have created some nifty GUI which sets all proper find & grep parameters as our options ? Does anyne know of a good modern Linux GUI application to catalog and search files ? maybe using a DB, not some big CSV / XML file ?

Comment: Do you mean something like [Baloo](https://community.kde.org/Baloo) for KDE? Have a look at `tracker`, `catfish`, `recoll` and [DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/de/download.html)!

Comment: How about [Recoll](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/index.html)? I use it, it works very well.

Comment: Plus there's [doodle](https://grothoff.org/christian/doodle/)!

Comment: The basic command-line commands `find` and `grep` are incredibly powerful, you'll get an idea by looking at the manpages. Because of that complexity I seriously doubt a GUI will ever be able to provide the full abilities of these commands. So in a way **Yes indeed**, you must learn to use these commands to *really* be able to do all kinds of queries, but on the other side of course there are some GUI solutions especially for simple queries.

Answer (score 2):

### Tracker

[image]

#### Description from [Tracker's Homepage](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker)

Tracker is a search engine, search tool and metadata storage system.
It allows you to find the proverbial needle in your computer's haystack as well as providing a one stop solution to the organisation, storage and categorisation of your data. Some plugins allow you to use Tracker in GNOME applications, for example: Totem and Nautilus.

#### Installation

```
sudo apt install tracker-gui
```

#### Getting started

You can configure Tracker by running `tracker-preferences` and access the simple search GUI by running `tracker-needle`. To index files you need to start `tracker daemon -s`, I recommend adding this command to your Autostart Applications (*System* → *Preferences* → *Startup Applications*). For more information browse the [website](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Tracker) and read `tracker --help`. An alternative GUI for Tracker is `catfish`, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/960457/507051).

Comment: Tracker-gui doesn't seem to be available in Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: You're right, although `tracker` is still available (see [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/tracker)), it's just the GUI they removed.

Answer (score 2):

### <sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub> Catfish

[image]

#### Description from [Catfish's homepage](http://www.twotoasts.de/index.php/catfish/) and [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/catfish-search)

Catfish is a GTK+ search utility written in Python. Its search is powered by `locate` and `find` behind the scenes, with search suggestions provided by `zeitgeist`. The advanced options allow filtering by date and file type. The interface is intentionally lightweight and simple, using only GTK+. Catfish can be used as a GUI for [`tracker`](https://askubuntu.com/a/960451/507051) and [`doodle`](https://grothoff.org/christian/doodle/) as well.

#### Installation

```
sudo apt install catfish
```

Answer (score 0):

### <sub><sub><sub>[image: icon]</sub></sub></sub> DocFetcher

[image: screenshot]

#### Description from [DocFetcher's homepage](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html)

DocFetcher is an Open Source desktop search application: It allows you to search the contents of files on your computer. — You can think of it as Google for your local files. The application runs in Java on Windows, Linux and OS X, and is made available under the [Eclipse Public License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Public_License). This way it's **portable** and can very well be stored externally.

For more information there's the [homepage](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html), the [wiki](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php) and the [forum](http://sourceforge.net/projects/docfetcher/forums/forum/702424).

### Installation

1. Install Java: [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)
2. Download DocFetcher from [sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/docfetcher/files/latest/download?source=typ_redirect)
3. Unzip the archive using your archive manager or

   ```
   unzip docfetcher-*-portable.zip
   ```
4. Navigate inside the extracted directory and run the program with

   ```
   ./DocFetcher-GTK3.sh
   ```

   or if DocFetcher doesn't start or the GUI behaves strangely:

   ```
   ./DocFetcher-GTK2.sh
   ```