# Oracle Java 8 u151 segmentation fault

Tags: java, openjdk, oracle

Any java commands get this error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

It's happened on ubuntu-desktop-16.04-x64 and Mint too.

Core dump: Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. #0 elf_machine_rela_relative (reloc_addr_arg=0x47ff743d69830, reloc=0x7ff742fd8420, l_addr=140699955408896) at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h:518 518 ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h: No such file or directory.

Any Idea? What's /sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h?

openjdk-8-jdk is ok. This problem only exists in Oracle Java 8.

Comment: Nothing important, it just tells you that segfault happened at function `elf_machine_rela_relative`, and by virtue of having debug symbols mentions it is defined at `dl-machine.h`, line 518; and that you don't have the file *(obviously, you didn't compile the package)*. How did you get Java in the first place, did you install it from Ubuntu repository, or rather downloaded it from somewhere?

Comment: @Hi-Angel , I tried multiple ways: downloading from http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main, using tar.gz. file which was downloaded oracle.com. In all ways, this error is happened. How do I resolve it? Where can I get /sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h?

Comment: Since you downloaded it manually, I'm guessing you've used `dpkg`, right? Try removing it, and installing again by using `gdebi` this time, perhaps there were some dependencies missing, and `dpkg` doesn't resolve them. I'm not sure why would you want it, but to peek at dl-machine.h  you can [e.g. here](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h); however note that you don't know at which commit it's been used, so it's likely you won't find anything interesting at 518 line.

Comment: Also, you didn't mention why do you try doing that manually. Did you try [answers from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)?

Comment: @Hi-Angel , I downloaded tar.gz file from oracle.com & extracted it then ran it. This error was shown.

Comment: @Hi-Angel , I tried another way: I used add apt-repository to add http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu , then I used apt-get to install oracle-java. It was installed but the error was shown when I run any java cmds

Comment: @Hi-Angel , What's the absolute path of dl-machine.h? Where should I put dl-machine.h? I can't find any directory named  sysdeps/x86_64!

Comment: Did you try package `openjdk-8-jdk` instead? About the dl-machine.h please read my first comment again — it's just source code, you won't get anything useful from it unless you want to build the package yourself, and then debug where it's failing.

Comment: @Hi-Angel , I want to put dl-machine.h source code in sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h path. But I can't find it. Where is the absolute path of sysdeps/x86_64 directory?

Comment: `/sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h` are the absolute paths, you can't find it because it only existed on packager's machine. Is there any reason you can't use `openjdk` if it works for you? As for the segfault — you can only report a bug to Oracle.