# How to install OpenJDK 10 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: java, openjdk, 19.04

Is there a way to install OpenJDK 10 on Ubuntu 19.04? Is there maybe a ppa available for that?

Since 19.04, there is only OpenJDK11 and 12 available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Comment: No, because since 19.04, only OpenJDK 11 is available.

Comment: The duplicate mentions OpenJDK in one of its answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenJDK 10 was non-LTS version of Java which has now its EOL in September, 2018. That means no future updates or fixes would be provided for this version. The JDK tarball can still be downloaded from OpenJDK archives and configured. To install OpeJDK 10 follow the steps below:

- Download the tarball

  ```
  wget https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk10/10.0.2/19aef61b38124481863b1413dce1855f/13/openjdk-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
  ```
- Unpack tar

  ```
  tar -xvf openjdk-10.0.2_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
  ```
- Move the extracted folder to /usr/lib/jdk

  ```
  sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jdk
  sudo mv jdk-10.0.2 /usr/lib/jdk
  ```
- Update alternatives

  ```
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jdk/jdk-10.0.2/bin/java" 1 
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jdk/jdk-10.0.2/bin/javac" 1
  ```
- Configure

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --config java
  sudo update-alternatives --config javac
  ```
- Verify the version

  ```
  $ java -version
  openjdk version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manually downloading the files from here

`https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa`

```
openjdk-10-jdk_10.0.2+13-1_16.04.6_amd64.deb
openjdk-10-jdk-headless_10.0.2+13-1_16.04.6_amd64.deb
openjdk-10-jre_10.0.2+13-1_16.04.6_amd64.deb
openjdk-10-jre-headless_10.0.2+13-1_16.04.6_amd64.deb
```

Then I installed them like this:

`sudo dpkg -i openjdk*.deb`