# How to install the JDK on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: jdk

I am trying to install the Java Development Kit (JDK) on Ubuntu Linux distribution, but I am unable to install it.

What are the steps to install it on Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Answer (score 0):

## Installing `default-jdk`

First, update the package list by running the command

```
sudo apt update
```

Now, install the default JDK

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

## Installing Java 11 or Java 13

Update the package list by running the command

```
sudo apt update
```

Install dependency

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

Add java repository

```
add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
```

Again update your package list

```
sudo apt update
```

Run the command to install `oracle-java11-installer` or `oracle-java13-installer` (ANY ONE)

```
sudo apt install oracle-java11-installer

sudo apt install oracle-java13-installer
```