# Java OpenJDK installation not working

Tags: java, openjdk

I recently dual booted Ubuntu with my Windows so I am completely new. I coded in Java on my Windows machine, but would like to do it on Ubuntu now. However, when trying to follow tutorials (e.g. [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java/88058#88058)) I get errors in my terminal which I'll add here.

```
milan@milan-Inspiron-7559:~$ sudo apt-get install default-jre
[sudo] password for milan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra java-common
  libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-11-jre
  openjdk-11-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-wqy-microhei
  | fonts-wqy-zenhei
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java default-jre default-jre-headless fonts-dejavu-extra
  java-common libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni openjdk-11-jre
  openjdk-11-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 37.5 MB/39.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 178 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Ign:1 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 openjdk-11-jre-headless amd64 11.0.7+10-2ubuntu2~19.10
Ign:2 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 openjdk-11-jre amd64 11.0.7+10-2ubuntu2~19.10
Ign:3 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 libatk-wrapper-java all 0.35.0-3
Err:4 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 libatk-wrapper-java-jni amd64 0.35.0-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
Err:3 http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 libatk-wrapper-java all 0.35.0-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 openjdk-11-jre-headless amd64 11.0.7+10-2ubuntu2~19.10
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/main amd64 openjdk-11-jre amd64 11.0.7+10-2ubuntu2~19.10
  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jre-headless_11.0.7+10-2ubuntu2~19.10_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-11-jre_11.0.7+10-2ubuntu2~19.10_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-atk-wrapper/libatk-wrapper-java_0.35.0-3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-atk-wrapper/libatk-wrapper-java-jni_0.35.0-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 197.155.77.2 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
milan@milan-Inspiron-7559:~$ apt-get update
Reading package lists... Done
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is End of Life as of July 2020. Please upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: I am running 19.10. I did not realise that that would be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS solved it.