# I downloaded a .sh.tar.gz package from the internet, how can install it?

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded a compressed package from the internet and I want to install it on Ubuntu 15.10, but I can't install it. How can I do that?

I tried to install it by running `sudo apt-install <package name in my computer >` but it gave me an error.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the name of the file and possibly what it is used for so that we can better help you try to install whatever it was that you downloaded from the internet?

Comment: What package did you download?

Comment: i visit this link  http://www.tryfeem.com/en/download.html to download feem wifi to share any thing with my friends and i download it for linux "\Feem_v3.0.4_Installer_For_Linux_x64.sh.tar.gz" .how can i install it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I've downloaded a .sh file - how do I install this?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/77247/ive-downloaded-a-sh-file-how-do-i-install-this)

Answer (score 1):

it's not sudo apt-install

it's sudo dpkg -i something.deb or sudo apt-get install something

Comment: dpkg is for local packages, apt for remote packages

Comment: i visit this link tryfeem.com/en/download.html to download feem wifi to share any thing with my friends and i download it for linux "\Feem_v3.0.4_Installer_For_Linux_x64.sh.tar.gz" .how can i install it ?

Comment: @crafter thank you , do you know how can i find wifi feem for ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

`dpkg` and `apt` are Package Managers for Debian and it's derivatives.  Your trying to install a package that wasn't packaged for a package manager.  As such, you must use the traditional tools provided by Linux. Those tools are ChangeMode,Copy, Tar, and Shell.  Try the following

```
cd /opt  <-- This goes here because it wasn't provided by a Ubuntu Package
mv -v /path/to/DownloadedFiles/Feem_v3.0.4_Installer_For_Linux_x64.sh.tar.gz /opt
sudo tar -zxvf Feem_v3.0.4_Installer_For_Linux_x64.sh.tar.gz
sudo chmod +x Feem_v3.0.4_Installer_For_Linux_x64.sh 
sudo sh Feem_v3.0.4_Installer_For_Linux_x64.sh
```