# How to uninstall termite installed from source?

Tags: software-uninstall

I installed termite terminal emulator by following [this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/77267/733268) and I got the installation package from [here on Github](https://github.com/Corwind/termite-install). Now I'm trying to uninstall it. I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/711795/733268), but it doesn't work.

I tried this:

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge termite
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package termite
```

The termite location on my system is:

[image: termite location]

Comment: The proper duplicate question is [How can I uninstall software?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1143/507051) IMO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I uninstall software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143/how-can-i-uninstall-software)

Comment: More info required. What have you tried so far? What was the result? Etc...

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I build a package from source how can I uninstall or remove completely?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely)

Comment: @user68186: Highly relevant but no duplicate imho since there's more at play in this case and it's not even immediately obvious that this happened.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Withdrawn.

Answer (score 9):

### Part 1

A look into the installation script shows that it downloads the source code of two pieces of software and builds and installs them using Make. As usually the build descriptions also include a rule to uninstall:

1. Open a terminal and change the current working directory to the one you used to execute [the installation script](https://github.com/Corwind/termite-install/blob/master/termite-install.sh).
2. Invoke the uninstallation rules of each installed piece of software:

   ```
   sudo make -C termite uninstall
   sudo make -C vte-ng uninstall
   ```
3. Update the shared library database:

   ```
   sudo ldconfig
   ```
4. Additionally and optionally you can remove the involved source code directories:

   ```
   rm -r termite vte-ng
   ```

### Part 2

The installation script also does a few other things that you can reverse:

- Remove the *alternatives* entry for `termite`:

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --remove x-terminal-emulator /usr/local/bin/termite
  ```

  If you had selected a different default terminal emulator manually before the installation of `termite` you can do so again with:

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
  ```
- Remove the (now broken) symbolic link to the *terminfo* file:

  ```
  sudo rm /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-termite
  ```

Comment: As you’ve never accepted an answer before: if this answers your question, don’t forget to click the grey ☑ under the number at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means “yes, this answer is valid”!

Answer (score 2):

In general, I'd do something like this:

```bsh
# if termite provided by a Ubuntu package
dpkg -S $(type -p termite)
# if it is, remove it through the package system
sudo apt-get --dry-run remove $(dpkg -S $(type -p termite) | cut -d: -f2)
```

but, if the `dpkg -S $(type -p termite)` doesn't show anthing, you installed `termite` another way.

```bsh
locate termite
```

should show you all the `termite` files, maybe you can find a `termite.tar` or something.

Comment: Except locate will only work if locate is installed and the DB is up to date. Find is probably a better option. E.g. `find / -type f -name termite`

Comment: OP didn't use the package manager to install the software. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you installed termite not through the package manager, approaches using `apt` and `dpkg` will likely not work

your best chance is do go to the directory vte-ng termite were respectively cloned to and try `make uninstall` (See this [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87111/if-i-build-a-package-from-source-how-can-i-uninstall-or-remove-completely) question).
For termite the `uninstall` is unfortunately not to nicely written, so it will leave man pages, desktop entry and the likes in place.

I am sure you also would like to undo the `x-terminal-emulator` stuff

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove x-terminal-emulator /usr/local/bin/termite
```