# How do I fix gnome-terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal

I installed termite and set it as my default terminal using `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/local/bin/termite 60`
 but decided I prefer the gnome terminal. The problem is that it seems to have broken, and whenever I try to open it, it returns

```
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached
```

Output from ls -alt /etc/alternatives: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yDj3pwMTCG/

Comment: I haven't used your other terminal but I would try `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-terminal` and hope that works.

Comment: You used an incorrect command to change the alternatives. Edit your question and show me `ls -alt /etc/alternatives` (use paste.ubuntu.com) and `cat /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator`. Be sure to use the {} formatting icon to make the pasted text human readable.

Comment: I did the first command, but I don't understand what you mean by the formatting icon.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been a problem with either Termite or the vte-ng library. Solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1010348/971943