# how to install the rpm package jdk-7u9-linux-i586.rpm?

Tags: java, jdk

I download the jdk-7u9-linux-i586.rpm (not the rpm.bin)

I use code `rpm -ivh jdk-7u9-linux-i586.rpm`.

But it cannot install it succesfully, why??

I use google to search the anwser, but they all about how to install a "bin" file, not the "rpm" I download at the java.com its file is the "rpm", not the "XXX.rpm.bin"

Now I have no idea about this.

Comment: Rpm packages are for Red Hat based distributions, although they can be installed on other distros. What errors are you getting? There's other ways to install jdk on Ubuntu: `http://askubuntu.com/questions/21561/how-to-install-jdk-and-netbeans`

Comment: You should follow this http://askubuntu.com/q/55848/65926

Comment: With Linux, you usually do not download stuff from websites. Check out the “Software Center” and search for the Java Devolpment Kit there.

Comment: @queueoverflow Since the Oracle JDK is no longer in the Ubuntu repositories, it will not be in the software center.

Answer (score 2):

In oracle.com there is an option to download a "Linux" version that is a tar.gz file which is the correct option in the case of Ubuntu.

However, it is possible to find 3rd party packages online that have Oracle Java packed as an installable package on Ubuntu, however, since these packages are from 3rd parties, trusting them is your responsibility.